# Filling a DataSet or a DataTable from a LINQ query result set

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, .net-3.5

How do you expose a LINQ query as an ASMX web service?

Usually, from the business tier, I can return a typed `DataSet` or a `DataTable` which can be serialized for transport over ASMX.

How can I do the same for a LINQ query? 
Is there a way to populate a typed `DataSet` or a `DataTable` via a LINQ query?

```
public static MyDataTable CallMySproc()
{
    string conn = "...";

    MyDatabaseDataContext db = new MyDatabaseDataContext(conn);
    MyDataTable dt = new MyDataTable();

    // execute a sproc via LINQ
    var query = from dr
                in db.MySproc().AsEnumerable
                select dr;

    // copy LINQ query resultset into a DataTable -this does not work !    
    dt = query.CopyToDataTable();
   
    return dt;
}
```

How could I put the result set of a LINQ query into a `DataSet` or a `DataTable`?

Alternatively, can the LINQ query be serializable so that I can expose it as an ASMX web service?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, `IEnumerable` has a `CopyToDataTable` method:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate") > new DateTime(2001, 8, 1)
    select order;

// Create a table from the query.
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Why won't that work for you?

Comment: To everyone wondering why CopyToDataTable() doesn't work on their machine: This function is not part of .NET 3.5 SP1 nor will it be of .NET 4.0; it has been restricted to  IEnumerable<DataRows> and does not work for IEnumerable<T> -- http://bit.ly/dL0G5

Answer (score 33):

To perform this query against a `DataContext` class, you'll need to do the following:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
    (from order in db.Orders.AsEnumerable()
        select new
        {
            order.Property,
            order.Property2
        })
    as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
return query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Without the `as IEnumerable<DataRow>;` you will see the following compilation error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 25):

Make a set of Data Transfer Objects, a couple of mappers, and return that via the .asmx.
You should *never* expose the database objects directly, as a change in the procedure schema will propagate to the web service consumer without you noticing it.

Answer (score 19):

If you use a return type of `IEnumerable`, you can return your **query** variable directly.

Answer (score 15):

Create a class object and return a `list(T)` of the query.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `IEnumerable` as the return type, it will return your query variable directly.

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
    (from order in db.Orders.AsEnumerable()
        select new
        {
            order.Property,
            order.Property2
        })
    as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
return query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, these solutions do not work for EF Core (at least not for EF Core 2.2). Casting to `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, as suggested in the other answers here, fails. Implementing this class and extension methods worked for me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/implement-copytodatatable-where-type-not-a-datarow.

Why it's not built into EF Core, I have not idea.