# Fastest way to fill DataTable from LINQ query using DataContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, ienumerable

I am trying to run a linq query but I need the result as a datatable as I am using that to store records from different queries in the same viewstate object.

The 2 versions below compile, but return an empty set. The exact error is *"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source"*. (and yes I have checked there is data):

```
MyDatabaseDataContext db = new MyDatabaseDataContext(conn); 
IEnumerable<DataRow> queryProjects = 
    (from DataRow p in db.STREAM_PROJECTs.AsEnumerable()
    where p.Field<int>("STREAM_ID") == StreamID
    select new
    {
        PROJECT_ID = p.Field<int>("PROJECT_ID"),
        PROJECT_NAME = p.Field<string>("PROJECT_NAME")
    }) as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
DataTable results = queryProjects.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

...

```
//(from p in db.STREAM_PROJECTs.AsEnumerable()
//where p.STREAM_ID == StreamID
//select new
//{
//    p.PROJECT_NAME,
//    p.PROJECT_ID
//}) as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
```

The examples in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16/how-do-i-fill-a-dataset-or-a-datatable-from-a-linq-query-resultset) don't seem to work in this situation either.

I guess I could just run a sql query command the old-fashioned way, but isn't linq supposed to be quicker?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
as IEnumerable<DataRow>
```

The `as` keyword performs a safe cast, not a conversion, which it seems like you might think that it's doing. The `as` keyword is semantically the same as doing this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> queryProjects = 
    (IEnumerable<DataRow>)(from DataRow p in db.STREAM_PROJECTs.AsEnumerable()
    where p.Field<int>("STREAM_ID") == StreamID
    select new
    {
        PROJECT_ID = p.Field<int>("PROJECT_ID"),
        PROJECT_NAME = p.Field<int>("PROJECT_NAME")
    });
```

Except the version with `as` won't throw an exception when it fails to cast your query object (which is an `IQueryable<T>`, where `T` is an anonymous type) to an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` (which it isn't).

Unfortunately, there is no built-in method that I'm aware of that will take an enumerable of a concrete type (like your anonymous type in this example) and turn it into a `DataTable`. Writing one wouldn't be too complicated, as you'd essentially need to get the properties reflectively then iterate over the collection and use those properties to create columns in a `DataTable`. I'll post an example in a few.

Something like this, placed in a static class within a namespace that you're `using`, should provide an extension method that will do what you want:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    DataTable output = new DataTable();

    foreach(var prop in properties)
    {
        output.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }

    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        DataRow row = output.NewRow();

        foreach(var prop in properties)
        {
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item, null);
        }

        output.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: I see - so it is just hiding the invalidcastexception? How do I get it into the datatable then?

Comment: @JumpingJezza: Yes; `as` is to be used in cases where you know that the object might not actually be the type you're expecting and isn't an "exceptional" case. The `as` keyword evaluates to `null` if the cast is invalid, and (as a result) can only be used with reference types and `Nullable<T>`. See the edit I just posted for a sample extension method that can turn any `IEnumerable<T>` to a `DataTable`.

Comment: Perfect! Plus I found out something new about `as` :)

Comment: I had to built in a check for Nullable Types since the output.Columns.Add call will fail if type is nullable