# LINQ to DataTable Easy and Fast

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable

I am new to LINQ, I want to convert LINQ query to DataTable

```
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(MyConncectionString);
    IEnumerable<DataRow> qry = (IEnumerable<DataRow>)(from tbl in db.Table1.AsEnumerable()
                                                     select tbl);
    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
    qry.CopyToDataTable(dt, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

But I got error

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.

Can anyone please help me that

Comment: Try changing to "var qry = from tbl in db.Table1 select tbl";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are basic concepts:

There are several LINQ providers shipped with the .Net framework

- LINQ to Objects. System.Linq. It's the LINQ core and it is designed to work with in-memory collections
- LINQ to XML. System.Xml.Linq To work with XML documents
- LINQ to DataSet.   To work with DataTable, and DataSet objects
- LINQ to SQL. System.Data.Linq It is used to work with SQL Server databases
- LINQ to Entities. (Entity Framework) Used to work with several databases. It provides a richer API

What I think you are trying to do is:

*From a query returned from a LINQ to SQL context, you want to return a collection of `DataRow` objects.*

**There's no simple conversion between a LINQ to SQL object and a DataRow, so if you insist you would need to use reflection to get the desired output**, [Fastest way to fill DataTable from LINQ query using DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4953209/1268570)

Now if you really want to work with the DataTable objects, then my recommendation is to use a strongly typed DataSet. To create one, simply add a new DataSet object to your project and from the Server Explorer drag tables like you would do with your LINQ to SQL objects

If possible, evaluate the decision to use `DataRow` and instead return the objects generated by LINQ To SQL, or even better create your custom DTO objects

About your code, I don't see any reason to try to use a `Datatable` object (unless you are nto posting that extra code to justify this decision). If you just want to set the `DataSource` property of a control, simply do the following:

```
var q = from tbl in db.Table1
        select tbl;

this.myControl.DataSource = q;
this.myControl.DataBind();
```

If you need, you can transform the result into an anonymous object and used it as the `DataSource`:

```
var q = from tbl in db.Table1
        select new
        {
           MyNewProperty = tbl.ExistingProperty,
           AnotherProperty = tbl.MyCoolerProperty
        };

this.myControl.DataSource = q;
this.myControl.DataBind();
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you. I was missing GridView.DataBind();

Comment: So, when you code 'this.myControl,Databind()' you are binding the control to q, right? If I perform any change to the data of this control, is this data be saved to the database?

Comment: No. In order to save it _automatically_ you would need to use a **data source control** such as an `EntityDataSource` or a `LinqDataSource` control

Answer (score 1):

I think is unnecessary here to convert into linq? as u already got the datatable and you are linq-ing and again converting it back to linq. So unless you have valid reason to linq here, you should stick with data table.

```
     DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(MyConncectionString);
     IEnumerable<DataRow> qry = (IEnumerable<DataRow>)(from tbl in db.Table1.AsEnumerable()
                                                 select tbl);
    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
    qry.CopyToDataTable(dt, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Should be,

```
    GridView1.DataSource = db.Table1
```