# How to Convert var to DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have following function -

```
public static DataTable getDetails(PersonContext context)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
IQueryable<Person> query = from p in context.Persons.Include("Employee")
                                                    .Include("Manager")
                                                    .Include("Activity")
                           where p.Activity.IsActive
                           select p;
var sorted = query.ToArray().OrderByDescending(p=>p.Activity.DateCreated);
dt = (DataTable)sorted;
return dt;
}
```

I can't test it.
My question is - will this function work. If no what changes should I make in it?

**Update**

```
public static DataTable getDetails(PersonContext context)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Details");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Department");
dt.Columns.Add("IsManager");
IQueryable<Person> query = from p in context.Persons.Include("Employee")
                                                    .Include("Manager")
                                                    .Include("Activity")
                           where p.Activity.IsActive
                           select p;
var sorted = query.ToArray().OrderByDescending(p=>p.Activity.DateCreated);
foreach(Person p in sorted)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(p.Name, p.Employee.Department,p.Manager.IsManager);
}
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Check those solutions [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/85368-c%23-convert-object-array-into-datatable/).
Hope this will help.

Comment: As is, this won't work as `sorted` will be ok type `IQueryable<Person>`. I believe you should better sort the results at the consuming side, not within the datatable itself. Sorting is a presentation layer's feature, not datalayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt = (DataTable)sorted;
```

is an invalid cast. The correct way is to add the returned array to dt using 
 
`dt.Rows.Add(query.ToArray().OrderByDescending(p=>p.Activity.DateCreated).toArray());`.
 You can find more information at [Adding Data To Datatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z16c79x4.aspx)

Comment: Create a DataRow from Person first. DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); Then add the necessary values to the row, dr["Name"] = p.Name;dr["Dept"] = p.Employee.Department and so on. Then finally dt.Rows.Add(dr); All this happens within the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks @prthrokz. I am following your way. However, I can't test it, but I am assuming, It will work now.

Answer (score 3):

OrderByDescending() returns an IEnumerable not a DataTable

This link answers what seems to be the same question. 
[LINQ to DataTable Easy and Fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491594/linq-to-datatable-easy-and-fast)

Answer (score 1):

If the return type of `OrderByDescending` **was**`DataTable` then the cast is not needed. The compiler knows the type of the method return type at compile time.

However `OrderByDescending` doesn't return a `DataTable` You need to construct it.