# Convert TimeSpan to Double in Datatable using Linq / Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I would like to convert this `DataTable`

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("timespan1", typeof(TimeSpan)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("timespan2", typeof(TimeSpan)));
```

into this

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("timespan1", typeof(double)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("timespan2", typeof(double)));
```

I've managed to do it this way.

```
Double d;        

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     dr = dtNew.NewRow();

     dr[0] = row.ItemArray[0];
     Double.TryParse(((TimeSpan)(row.ItemArray[1])).TotalMinutes.ToString(), out d);

     dr[1] = d;
     Double.TryParse(((TimeSpan)(row.ItemArray[2])).TotalMinutes.ToString(), out d);

     dr[2] = d;
     dtNew.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
}
```

Is there any way to use Linq or a lambda expression? I would like to bind this `new <double> DataTable` to a stacked bar chart. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you converting the TimeSpan to a string and then parsing it? Why not just use `dr[1] = ((TimeSpan) row.ItemArray[1]).TotalMinutes;`?

Comment: That really make sense. I'm using TryParse as a safe conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have right now, is correct except that you should use `TotalMinutes` directly without converting it to a string, *(like Jon Skeet mentioned in the comment)*.

LINQ is for querying data, it shouldn't be used for modifying the data. Your current code with a `foreach` loop is clear and conveys the intent.

But if you are looking for LINQ syntax then you can do:

```
var dummyQuery = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(dr => 
                dtNew.Rows.Add(dr.Field<TimeSpan>("timespan1").TotalMinutes,
                               dr.Field<TimeSpan>("timespan2").TotalMinutes))
                    .ToList();//To Iterate
```

This will populate the new `DataTable`, `dtNew` with `TotalMinutes` values from both column.

Another option is to project your query result in `Select` to an anonymous type and then use reflection to create `DataTable` like [Fastest way to fill DataTable from LINQ query using DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953209/fastest-way-to-fill-datatable-from-linq-query-using-datacontext)