# Load DataSet via LINQ-to-SQl

Tags: c#, linq

I have a stored procedure that returns a DataSet.This stored procedure is exposed in my C# code via an Entity Data Model. How do I get the DataSet in my code? The context keeps trying to automatically generate a strongly-typed set of objects. However, those objects only represent the first result set. My DataSet has 4 result sets in it. Here is the code I'm using:

```
using (DBDataContext context = new DBDataContext())
{
  var myDataSet = context.LoadData();   // Load data is the name of my sproc

  // how do I get a DataSet here?
}
```

How do I get a DataSet via LINQ-to-SQL, or LINQ-to-EntityDataModel, or whatever it is called?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fill a DataSet or a DataTable from a LINQ query resultset ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16/how-do-i-fill-a-dataset-or-a-datatable-from-a-linq-query-resultset)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as this question is about how to handle a stored procedure that returns multiple result sets with different columns in LINQ to SQL. The DataSet bit is a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple result sets then you need to write some code - but it's not hard:

There's a few examples out there on the web - e.g.:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dditweb/archive/2008/05/06/linq-to-sql-and-multiple-result-sets-in-stored-procedures.aspx
- http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-to-return-Multiple-Results
- http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-GB&q=linq+to+sql+multiple+result+sets ;)

They mostly show what's needed as extending your partial datacontext with something like:

```
    <FunctionAttribute(Name:="dbo.GetMultipleSets")> _
    <ResultType(GetType(Type_1))> _
    <ResultType(GetType(Type_2))> _
    Public Function GetMultipleSets() As IMultipleResults
        Dim result As IExecuteResult = Me.ExecuteMethodCall(Me, CType(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod, MethodInfo))
        Dim results As IMultipleResults = DirectCast(result.ReturnValue, IMultipleResults)
        Return results
    End Function
```

or in C# as something like:

```
    [Function("dbo.GetMultipleSets"]
    [ResultType(typeof(Type_1))]
    [ResultType(typeof(Type_2))]
    public IMultipleResults GetMultipleSets()
    {
        IExecuteResult result = ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()));
        IMultipleResults results  = (IMultipleResults)result.ReturnValue;
        return results;
    }
```

Hope that helps

Stuart