# Linq Return grouped Table as Datatable

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.5

I wrote a function that returns a DataTable Object. For the following code

```
Public Function GetArtikelsAbove50(ByVal limit As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim query = _Set.Ten_Most_Expensive_Products.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.UnitPrice > limit) _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) x.UnitPrice)
    Return query.CopyToDataTable
End Function
```

`query` is an `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of SPTest.northwindDataSet.Ten_Most_Expensive_ProductsRow)` Object. The code runs and everything is good. But if I add:

```
.GroupBy(Function(x) x.UnitPrice)
```

the compiler underlinies the return object (`query.CopyToDataTable`). query is now an `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Linq.IGrouping(Of Decimal, SPTest.northwindDataSet.Ten_Most_Expensive_ProductsRow))` Object so CopyToDataTable is not a member of that anymore. Since I need the `.GroupBy` Function (some goes for `.Sum`)) I am looking for a way to use it in combination with the `.CopyToDataTable`. Is that possible and if so, how can I accomplish it?

I thought, that mybe returning a `DataView` Objeckt (with `Return query.AsDataView`) would work, but same error.

**Hint:**
During my research I found that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16/filling-a-dataset-or-datatable-from-a-linq-query-result-set) question a user mentioned that the function .CopyToDataTable *"has been restricted to IEnumerable and does not work for IEnumerable(of T)"*. I am not so familiar with Datasets and I am not sure if this helps to solve the problem. Just wanted to share the information, maybe it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that applying `GroupBy` changes what comes out of your expression.  Your enumerable is now an IEnumerable of

```
 System.Linq.IGrouping(Of Decimal, SPTest.northwindDataSet.Ten_Most_Expensive_ProductsRow)
```

and not just of

```
 SPTest.northwindDataSet.Ten_Most_Expensive_ProductsRow
```

`CopyToDataTable` is an extension function on `IEnumerable(of DataRow)`, so it isn't available for this new anonymous type.

As for what to do... well, to get the function back, you'd need to transform your new type into a `DataRow` or a subclass of `DataRow`.

For example, you could create a new table with your desired row structure in your `DataSet` (let's call it `NewTable` for this example), which will cause a new, strongly-typed class called `NewTableRow` to be generated.

You could then write a `.Select` statement to transform the `System.Linq.IGrouping(Of Decimal, SPTest.northwindDataSet.Ten_Most_Expensive_ProductsRow)` objects into `NewTableRow` objects.

The `IEnumerable(Of SPTest.northwindDataSet.NewTableRow)` instance that would result would have `CopyToDataTable` available again.

ETA:  an example.  Disclaimer:  this was written in C# and auto-translated to VB, so there may be some quirks.  But you should get the idea.

```
' We need an instance of the the target table to access the NewRow method
Dim newTable As New NewTable 
Dim newRows = query.[Select](Function(g) ' We're using an anonymous method here, but you could make it a regular method.
  'A quirk of DataTable & DataRow: you can't just "new" up a DataRow.  You have to use the
  'NewRow or generated, strongly-typed NewXXXXRow method to get a new DataRow.
  Dim newRow = newTable.NewNewTableRow() 
  ' You can now set the properties on your new strongly-typed DataRow.
  newRow.UnitPrice = g.Key   
  newRow.Quantity = g.Sum(Function(d) d.Quantity)
  ' Don't forget to return the result!
  Return newRow
End Function)
```

Or, you could use the `AddNewTableRow` method to create AND add your new row to your target table.  You wouldn't even need to use `CopyToDataTable`!

Comment: Hello Ann, thanks for the answer. concerning the section before the last: Could you maybe give me more information on how to use a .Select Statement to transfrom my object into a NewTableRow object?