# Cannot copy data from query to datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a small problem, which I just cannot find how to fix it.

For my data table, Dictionar.DtDomenii, I need to copy the unique data from my other data table, Dictionar.Dt.

I wrote a query, but when using `query.CopyToDataTable()` to copy the data into my `DtDomenii` table, the "CopyToDataTable" function does not show...

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an easier way to copy distinct data (categories from my example) from one data table to another?

PS: I've already read the information from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
void LoadCategories()
{
    var query = (from cat in Dictionar.dt.AsEnumerable()
                 select new 
                        {
                            categorie = categorii.Field<string>("Categoria")
                        }).Distinct();

    // This statement does not work: 
    Dictionar.dtDomenii = query.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: Try using DataRow, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16/filling-a-dataset-or-datatable-from-a-linq-query-result-set

Comment: The accepted answers' commentators claim that this way is not supported after .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Only collections of **DataRow**s can use the `CopyToDataTable` method. For example:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable(); // this works

List<DataRow> dataRows = new List<DataRow>();
dataRows.CopyToDataTable(); // this also works

List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.CopyToDataTable(); // this does not work
```

The `select new...` part of your query is converting the **DataRow**s into **object**s. You need to convert the objects back into DataRows before you can use the `CopyToDataTable` method.

You *might* have better luck doing something like this:

```
DataTable copy = Dictionar.dt
   .AsEnumerable()       // now an enumerable of DataRow
   .Distinct()           // remove duplicates, still an enumerable of DataRow
   .CopyToDataTable();   // done!
```

You can also make a complete copy of the table with `Dictionar.dt.Copy()`, then remove the duplicate rows manually.